# How do I edit jquery.validate message in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have installed jquery.validate by bower.

and I wanna edit message above.

```
messages: {
    required: "This field is required.",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    maxlength: $.validator.format( "Please enter no more than {0} characters." ),
    minlength: $.validator.format( "Please enter at least {0} characters." ),
    rangelength: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long." ),
    range: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1}." ),
    max: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}." ),
    min: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}." ),
    step: $.validator.format( "Please enter a multiple of {0}." )
}
```

If I edit message in bower_components folder.
I can see changed result. but another client install this Project, they will don't.

I don't want.

how i do?
where I add message edit process?

Comment: why aren't you using angular built in validation?

Comment: cause our project use template that is bought by my company. so my boss order using jquery. angular only for SPA.

Answer (score 0):

resolve this problem.

I add above.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "This field is required.",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
  });
```

Comment: Where are you running this? Should be in a directive

Comment: this source is running in controller. that's not directive. this method can using jquery in angular.